# To enable different pages to be opened according to the selection of the radio buttons on the registration page

Tags: android, database, android-studio, kotlin, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons on my user registration page. If the user has registered by clicking the first radio button, I want to open the page according to him when he opens the application again, and if he has registered by clicking the second radio button, I want to show the page accordingly. How can I do that ?

```
class SignUpPage : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpPageBinding
private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySignUpPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    auth = Firebase.auth

}

fun loginSignUp (view: View){

    val name = binding.nameText.text.toString()
    val surname = binding.surnameText.text.toString()
    val email = binding.emailText.text.toString()
    val password = binding.PasswordText.text.toString()
    val button = binding.radioButton4.isChecked
    val button2 = binding.radioButton5.isChecked

    if(name.equals("")|| surname.equals("")|| email.equals("") || password.equals("") || button.equals("") || button2.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Lütfen Tüm Alanları Doldurun.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }



   else if (radioButton4.isChecked){
       auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnSuccessListener {
           val intent = Intent(this@SignUpPage,AccetpActivity::class.java)
           startActivity(intent)
           finish()
       }

    }
    else if(radioButton5.isChecked){
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@SignUpPage,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@SignUpPage,it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: show your current code

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code should not be share as images but as properly formatted using the WYSIWIG

Comment: Where are you saving that?

Comment: I didn't know that. I shared my codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can store value of radio button which selected by user in Android Shared preferences.
When user reopen the app, check the value from preference in splash activity of your app and open activity as per value.

Shared pref ref: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences